# Bowling score calculator in C

Tags: c, arrays

This is a homework problem. I'm currently in the process of writing a program that calculates one's bowling score. My logic is to use multidimensional arrays with 9 frames as the rows and 2 throws as the columns. I will account for the 10th frame at the very end due to its unique nature of having possibly up to three rolls. The addition of strikes and spares also complicate the question, so I felt like I needed to use arrays to keep track of past and future rolls. I know it's not required but I couldn't think of another way.

Here is my code so far:

```
for (i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &score[i][j]);
        tempTotal += score[i][j];
    }   
}
printf("temporary: %d\n", tempTotal);
//strike
for (i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        if(score[i][0] == 10 && score[i][1] == 0)
        {
            total = tempTotal + score[i+1][0] + score[i+1][1];
        }
//spare
        else if ((score[i][0] + score[i][1]) == 10)
        {   
            total = tempTotal + score[i+1][0];
        }
        else
        {
            total = tempTotal;
        }
    }
}
printf("result: %d\n", total);
```

Here is an update of my progress. As per the comments, I used scanf to fill up my multidimensional array first. And then I looked through the array to account for the cases of strikes and spares. The code works until there are consecutive strikes and/or spares. How do I account for the accumulation of consecutive spares and/or strikes? Am I supposed to add additional conditional statements within my strike and spare conditions to account for if score[i+1][0] is another strike in which case I have to account for that additional 10 points plus the next three throws as well? How can I make such a conditional statement that comprehensively searches through the entire array like that? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you keep score in bowling, you always add the score to current and previous frames, never future ones. Your program should work the same way.

Comment: Thanks to jim. I realized that and I'm currently scanfing all my values in my data structure first and then recalling previous values. I'll try to post and update soon. Thanks to Joachim as well. I wasn't aware of that feature.